# Is possible to retrieve data and download files from outlook without password using ExChangeLib (EWS)?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, exchangelib

I'm trying to access data from Outlook and can download files from exchangelib with a password. But I'd like access without a password. Do we've any alternate for this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to "this stuff"? Meaning an alternative to security? No.

The best you can do without credentials is to use Outlook Object Model on a machine where Outlook is already installed and configured to access the folders and messages from a mailbox in the configured local profile.

Comment: this thread was between an organization and able to download only excel files.

Comment: Doesn't matter - it is either you have the credentials and access an arbitrary mailbox or you run locally and can access locally cached (by Outlook) data or you piggyback on an active Outlook session and access the data accessible in that session using the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: By any chance, could you please share some sample piece of code for passwordless?

Comment: To do what? In what language? Using which API?

Comment: only to access outlook without a password and I'm using exchangelib (Python).

Comment: Once again, can't do exchangelib without credentials. Outlook Object Model is your only choice if you don't have the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use exchangelib to connect to the Exchange server without credentials of some sort, but exchangelib supports a variety of auth methods, and not all credentials contain a password. OAuth uses tokens, Kerberos and SSPI use a security context already available in your Windows session, certificate-based auth uses an on-disk file AFAIK, etc.

Comment: Could you please guide me to use the OAuth token? or any piece of code in python?

Comment: All the different auth mechanisms are documented here: https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/